# getString from class that implements Serializable

Tags: android

I have class that implements Serializable because I need to pass it between activities:

```
Day tempDay = new Day();
Intent i = new Intent(this, DayCreator.class);
i.putExtra("DayClass", tempDay);
startActivity(i);
```

But in Day class I need to read some string as so:

```
context.getString(R.string.sick_list);
```

If I pass to this class context as so via constructor:

```
Day tempDay = new Day(context);
```

I get an error when starting DayCreator activity:

```
Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object
```

This make scence because context is not serializable.

So... How can I get strings from class that implements Serializable?

Comment: "But in Day class I need to read some string as so" -- IMHO, `DayCreator` should read that string (or possibly whatever activity is the one that starts `DayCreator`). `Day` should be treated as some sort of model object, having nothing to do with string resources.

Comment: It's very dangerous hold `context` reference on objects. It is a better approach to make the methods that need a context receive as parameter, use it and return without saving a reference to it

Comment: In Day class I have function that return different strings depending on the inner calculations, those string are located in xml file. There is nothing to do with DayCreator

Comment: Use a Utility Class for that. Create a method and pass the day instance and context to it, then return the specific data you want .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do not pass context to `POJO` class**.
A simple workaround is just let your component read the String and pass it to the `Day` Object. like below in you component(Activity or Service).

```
 Day tempDay = new Day();
 tempDay.setName((getString(R.string.app_name));
```

Answer (score 1):

While you try to send whole model object in through bundle.. it should be like this

your `Day` class change like this

```
public class QrCode implements Parcelable {

    public static final Creator<QrCode> CREATOR = new Creator<QrCode>() {
        @Override
        public QrCode createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new QrCode(in);
        }

        @Override
        public QrCode[] newArray(int size) {
            return new QrCode[size];
        }
    };

    @SerializedName("sno")
    private int mSNo;

    public QrCode(){

    }

    public QrCode(Parcel in) {
        mSNo = in.readInt();
    }


    public int getSNo() {
        return mSNo;
    }

    public void setSNo(int SNo) {
        mSNo = SNo;
    }
    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeInt(mSNo);
    }
}
```